# Java volatile and synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, volatile

1. I know that volatile keyword refresh all the invisible data i.e. if some thread read volatile variable all potential invisible variables/references (not only the variable that will be read) will be okey(visible i.e. with correct values) after this reading. Right? But what about synchronized ? Is it the same ? If in synchronized block we read 3 variables for example will all other varibles will be visible?
2. What will hapen if one thread change the value of some variable (for example set varible "age" from 2 to 33) from non-synchronized block and after this thread die ? The value could be written in the thread stack, but main thread maybe will not see this change, the background thread will die and the new value is gone and can not be retrieved?
3. And last question if we have 2 background threads and we know that our main thread will be notified (in some way) just before every one of them will die and our thread will wait both of them to finish their work and will continue after that, how we can assure that all variables changes(which are made by the background threads) will be visible to the main thread? We can just put synchronized block after the background thread finishes or ? We don't want to access variables that are changed from the background threads with synchronized blocks every time after this threads are dead (because it's overhead), but we need to have their right values ? But it is unnatural to read some fake volatile variable or to use fake synchronized block(if it refresh all data) just to refresh all data.

I hope that my questions are explained well.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully covering the whole topic from the level your question seems to imply will require more than a StackOverflow.com answer, so **I recommend looking for a good book on multi threading programming**.

`volatile` guarantee that the read and write accesses to the qualified variable are totally ordered with respect to other accesses to the same`volatile` variable<sup>1</sup>.
It does this by preventing the `volatile` read and write accesses to be reorder with previous or future instructions and enforcing that all the side effects before the access of the writing thread are visible to a reading thread.

This means that volatile variable are read and written as you see in your code and like the instructions were executed one at a time, beginning the next one only when all the side effects of the previous are completed and visible to every other thread.

To better understand what this means and why this is necessary, look at this question of mine on [difference between Memory Barriers and lock prefixed instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578999/difference-between-memory-barriers-and-lock-prefixed-instruction/30583851#30583851).

**Note** that `volatile` in Java is **much much much stronger** than `volatile` in C or C++.  It does guarantee more that the usual treating of read/write access as a side effect with regard to optimization purposes. This means that is doesn't simply imply that the variable is read from the memory every time, a Java `volatile` is a memory barrier.

The `synchronized` block simply guarantees exclusive (i.e. one thread at a time) execution of a block of code.
It doesn't imply that all the thread see the memory access is the same order, a thread could see first the write to a protected shared data structure and then the write to the lock!

<sup><sub>1</sub> In some circumstances, where a full memory barrier is emitted, this may enforce that writes and reads to all volatile variables made by a thread T will be visible to other threads in T program order. Note that this not suffices for synchronization as there is still no relationship between inter-thread accesses.</sup>

---

1. No.
2. Shared vars are not on the stack of any thread, copy of their value can be but the variables exists independently of any thread.
   When a thread dies gracefully, the write is done and can be retrieved (beware of memory ordering again).
   If the thread dies forcefully, it could be interrupted anywhere. In any way the actual Java assignment is implemented if the thread stops before the write to the shaded var (by direct assignment or by copying a local value on the stack) then the write never happened.
3. You don't need `synchronized`, just `volatile` as the main thread only reads  and the background threads only write (different vars).

Comment: Can you offer me a book for concurrent programming? Is "Java concurrency in practice"  good enough? I am trying to read it now, but it is not lightweight for me . Thanks for your answer and attention.

Comment: @DPM It should do, hold on! :)

Comment: Thank you ! 
About this written for volatile - "When one thread writes to a volatile variable, and another thread sees that write, the first thread is telling the second about all of the contents of memory up until it performed the write to that volatile variable" , this mean that all variables will be "refreshed" i.e. will be with the real values for the reader thread. Isn't that a big overhead to "refresh" all of them, not only the variable which is declared as volatile.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DPM this has to do with how the CPU works. It means that the CPU cannot start a reading instruction too early (yes it can start instruction before their "right" time) when the writing instruction is not done yet. It also means what is technically called "writes propagation", i.e. if the write are done in some CPU internal cache, they must propagate to a memory visible by all other CPU. However this is done incrementally and asynchronously by the hardware , so again the statement is to be read as: "The propagation process must have completed before starting the reading".

Comment: First of all, the guarantees made for `volatile` variables only apply to writes and subsequent reads *of the same variable*. Second, the same guarantees are made for `synchronized` blocks when they use *the same object* as monitor. Then, and only then, all actions made by a thread prior to leaving a `synchronized` block *happens-before* actions made by another thread after entering a `synchronized` block. This is not just about how a CPU works (they work differently) but what a JVM’s optimizer can do with your code.

Comment: @Holger true, but `volatile` access are implemented in term of memory barriers and I not aware of any architecture that has word granularity for barriers. No one suggested that two general synchronized blocks are ordered in the HB relationship, they are just code protected by locks: different locks different orders. This is not just about what JVM can and cannot do, this is how the JVM reifies the memory ordering of a generic CPU, if you don't get it you'll never really get how JVM work. This is about how CPU works, or else why over complicating things with SW and HB relationships?

Comment: @knm241: the HB relationship is how Java’s memory model is specified and the JVM’s optimizer adheres to that specification and nothing else. In other words, if it can prove that a variable is not visible to other threads, there is no HB relationship and no memory barrier will be generated. Similarly, `synchronized` on a local object has no effect. That’s what already happens today and you can expect even more optimizations in the future. On the other hand, if a particular CPU can’t provide the necessary barriers, a JVM has to work-around it, to fulfill the *specification*, nothing else matters

Comment: Besides that, there are practical aspects. If you read a different `volatile` variable, how do you know that the other thread has already written to his own variable? Since you don’t know, you don’t know whether it has passed its memory barrier before you passed yours. And without that knowledge, there is no thread safety.

Comment: @holgetr that's true. I didn't know JVM was doing such optimizations. This changes the things. I'll update the answer thanks for pointing this out. What I want to stress out however is just that by knowing how the CPUs work you can easily understand JVM memory model, by not knowing you'll never build and intuition on it.

Comment: @Holger Page 222 of the [java 8 specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf), it says "...because each update to
i must be reflected in the shared value for i before the update to j".

Comment: @Holger Also look at [this page](http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) its says "The keyword volatile prevents this problem because it establishes a HB relationship between the write to `turn` and the write to `intentFirst`".

Comment: I don’t know what you want to tell me with these links. They are not contradicting what I said.

Comment: @Holger but they are supporting the fact that volatile access are total ordered, aren't they? A write to `j`/`intentFirst` cannot be visible before a write to `i`/`turn` and you said that HB for volatiles only apply to the same var (as written in the java specs btw).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84009/discussion-between-knm241-and-holger).

Answer (score 4):

Reading the value of a volatile variable creates a happens-before relationship between the writing from one thread and the reading of another.

See http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html:

> The Java volatile modifier is an example of a special mechanism to
>   guarantee that communication happens between threads. When one thread
>   writes to a volatile variable, and another thread sees that write, the
>   first thread is telling the second about all of the contents of memory
>   up until it performed the write to that volatile variable.

Synchronized blocks create a happens-before relationship as well. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor
>   happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method
>   entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation
>   is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking
>   happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that
>   monitor.

Which have the same effect on visibility.

If a value is written without any kind of synchronization then there is no guarantee that other threads will ever see this value. If you want to share values across threads, you should be adding some kind of synchronization or locking, or using volatile.

Answer (score 4):

All your questions are answered in [the java.util.concurrent package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility).

> 1. But what about synchronized?

Here's what the documentation says:

> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that monitor.

.

> 2. The value could be written in the thread stack, but main thread maybe will not see this change, the background thread will die and the new value is gone and can not be retrieved?

If the value is written in the thread stack, then we're talking about a local variable. Local variable are not accessible anywhere except in the method declaring that variable. So if the thread dies, of course the stack doesn't exist and the local variable doesn't exist either. If you're talking about a field of an object, that's stored on the heap. If no other thread has a reference to this object, and if the reference is unreachable from any static variable, then it will be garbage collected.

> 3. and our thread will wait both of them to finish their work and will continue after that, how we can assure that all variables changes(which are made by the background threads) will be visible to the main thread

The documentation says:

> All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join on that thread.

So, since the main thread waits for the background threads to die, it uses join(), and every action made by the background threads will be visible by the main thread after join() returns.